# Is there a Java interface of webhdfs to get data from hadoop cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, interface

I want to write a project outside of the hadoop cluster, which can read data from the cluster, however, the document offered by the office website only give the "curl" method.
Is there any interface for Java to access to hadoop cluster?

Comment: There's an entire Java HDFS API; are you talking about something besides that?

Comment: I know the FileSystem API: org.apache.hadoop.fs
However, this class cannot operate outside of the cluster, the client cannot connect to the slaves
And I hear that the webHdfs offer the method to operate the filesystem outside. But I don't know the Java interface.

Comment: the HDFS API can operate outside the cluster, in that it need not be run within a Hadoop job.  You do need to have the ability to connect to the name node over the network, but that would be true for webHdfs as well.

Comment: I have tested it, but no, there is an error:

INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream 192.168.0.101:50010 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 66000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/192.168.0.101:50010]
12/05/28 17:22:50 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Abandoning block blk_-6350835189174762628_6082

Well, outside the cluster, I mean outside the local network. only the namenode have domain.

Comment: I have the same problem currently, my Hadoop cluster(Actually it's a Spark cluster as well) is running on EC2 machines on AWS.
I'm running Java code that need to access the HDFS outside the cluster, Running the code from my local computer fails,
The reason is that Amazon Machines have internal IP's that are being resolved inside the Amazon servers and if you are outside of Amazons Domain you won't be able to resolve these addresses.
The temporary solution is writing the code on my machine, and then running the code on An AWS EC2 server that is able to resolve the addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at cloudera's HOOP...provides access to all HDFS operations including read/write over HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Hoop was replaced by webhdfs. Cloudera no longer supports the HOOP server endpoint required for it to work. Webhdfs is built into the hadoop stack and is much more integrated. It just needs to be enabled.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using 1.0.0+ version of hadoop look into the `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem` class.

If it's not already enabled you should be able to 'enable' it by setting the following configuration property in hdfs-core.xml:

- `dfs.webhdfs.enabled` = `true`

You'll need to restart your Name Node after making this change, you should see the following in your namenode log file:

> ```
> 2012-05-22 06:23:42,176 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: dfs.webhdfs.enabled = true
> 2012-05-22 06:23:42,177 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added filter 'SPNEGO' (class=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.AuthFilter)
> 2012-05-22 06:23:42,179 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: addJerseyResourcePackage: packageName=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.web.resources;org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources, pathSpec=/webhdfs/v1/*
> 2012-05-22 06:23:42,191 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50070
> 2012-05-22 06:23:42,192 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 50070 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 50070
> 2012-05-22 06:23:42,192 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50070
> ```

Now you can use the following to use Web Hdfs progamatically:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(), conf);
```

Comment: I can't find "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem class".

Comment: What version of hadoop are you running (like i said, you need v1.0.0+)

Comment: where would be the user/password ?

Answer (score 0):

yes.there is web interface to communicate with Job tracker node to know status of a job and all client side information

Answer (score 0):

The following Java libraries are available:

- [hadoop-hdfs](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs)
- [webhdfs-java-client](https://github.com/longbozhan/webhdfs-java-client)